# Complementary array Matlab

Tags: matlab

We've got an array of values, and we would like to create another array whose values are not in the first one.

Example:

```
load('internet.mat')
```

The first column contains the values in MBs, we have thought in something like:

```
MB_no = setdiff(v, internet(:,1))
```

where v is a 0 vector whose length equals to the number of rows in internet.mat. But it just doesn't work.

So, how do we do this?

Comment: What is in v? How did you generate v? Also why should v have the same number of elements as internet(:,1)? Please give small example dataset of internet(:,1) and of v

Comment: I think the above person has misunderstood the usage of `setdiff`. If one puts a vector of zeros and (say) 1st vector in `setdiff`, then the 1st vector will not be removed from the original data. You should read the function help [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html)

Comment: You described what should not be in the new array, please also describe what should be in the new array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the range of possible values to define what values are not in `internet` . Say the range is `v = 1:10` then `setdiff(v,internet(:,1))` will give you the values in `1:10` that are not in the first column of `internet`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you don't want the first column. 
You can simply do:

```
MB_no=internet(:,2:end);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming `internet(:,1)` has only positive integers and you wish to find which are the integers in `[1,...,max( internet(:,1) )]` that do **not** appear in that range you can simply do

```
app = [];
app( internet(:,1) ) = 1;
MB_no = find( app == 0 );
```

This is somewhat like *bucket sort*.